# Open android-app scheme with Chrome on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, android-chrome, firefox-android

I was wondering how I'd have to configure my app to open it with `android-app://application.id`?

```
adb shell am start android-app://application.id
```

The [URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME) seems not to work as documented. Instead Chrome and Firefox only open a `market://` link to my app.

For Chrome I found [a documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) only describing the `intent://` scheme.

When the intent filter contains the `DEFAULT` and `BROWSABLE` category it works with *Firefox*.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `<data../>` describing URI in `intent-filter` for your component, like so,

```
<intent-filter>
   ...

   <data android:scheme="android-app"/>
</intent-filter>
```

and on your site part define intent like this

```
intent:#Intent;scheme=android-app;package=your_package;end
```

**UPDATE.**
Didn't realize that scheme was a reserved one, although my solution works for any scheme you define.
I looked up the sources of the Intent class it seems you have to define your URI like this

```
android-app://your_package
```

OR

```
android-app://your_package/ 
#Intent;action=com.example.MY_ACTION;end
```

First line of the `parseUri` method in the Androids Intent class

```
final boolean androidApp = uri.startsWith("android-app:");
```

Worth to mention: This scheme was added on API 22.

I've tested it works with `a` tag, and as @tynn mentioned in the comments also for `window.open()` and `location.href` and **not working from** the address bar in Chrome.

Comment: The android-app scheme is one handled from within the system. Not one you'd declare yourself. Have a look at the `adb` command I posted. That's working for me.

Comment: I looked up further, please check my updated answer. Hope this helps

Comment: My intention is to open this automatically. Actually I made it work somehow from _Firefox_. When I type `android-app://application.id` in the address bar and open it, it will open the app or the market if the app is not installed. Sadly Chrome just opens the search and Chrome is my main use-case. I'll update the question later with my findings. Thanks for your efforts so far!

Comment: I was testing with `<a href="android-app://app.id">..` on Chrome, it worked for me.

Comment: So basically it works from a link, but not from the address bar. That's really confusing. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to work with `a` and `window.open()` and `location.href`. Could you add this point to your answer. Then I'll just accept it.

Comment: great, helpful.