# Run Android apps from a HTML page

Tags: javascript, android, html, launcher

I am in desperate need of help for I can't wrap my head around this.
I want to create an Android launcher for Android boxes using HTML.
I have a program that compiles HTML files to an APK called Weeb2APK that works well.

The only part I'm missing is how to launch apps.
I don't need to share data between apps but it would be nice if the HTML code could check if the app it's trying to launch is installed else go get it from a website.

So far I have this

```
<activity
    android:name="com.yoku.marumovie.analytics"
    android:label="@string/application_name">

    <!-- ... -->            

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="flickr.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/photos/" />
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.flickr.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/photos/" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Do I need an activity for every app?
How do I call the action from 
Yes, each app will have its own image.
If someone has a sample, this would help tremendously.  I find it easer to learn that way.

David

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is a year-old question, but it may help someone..*

I also had a need for this (on the *Obsidian.MD* app), and found the `android-app://` schema - with the application's package name specified in the URI. For example:

```
android-app://com.android.chrome
```

[On Android this link should launch Chrome.](https://android-app://com.android.chrome)

---

Note that, because of the intent filter [`CATEGORY_BROWSABLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_BROWSABLE), the schema will work as a hyperlink, but *not* when typed directly into the address bar.

It seems to be rather obscure; its difficult to find *any* documentation or information at all, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60277466/open-android-app-scheme-with-chrome-on-android) is another brief mention of it.